# Convert image to Bytes in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, base64, byte

Running the following code I'm getting the error that in the screenshot. I think the problem is that I'm trying to `readAsBytesSync();`

Any idea to resolve this error ?

```
String bytes = base64Encode(Io.File(path).readAsBytesSync());
```

[image]

Comment: Your `String path` looks like `"File: '/path/'"` instead of `"/path/"`. Otherwise your code is fine

Comment: how are you defining the image file path? Also, I do this to convert to bytes but your error isn't here: Base64Encoder().convert(_image.readAsBytesSync())

Comment: I figure out this! Now on the server side the probem is to convert the base64 (which is a big big path from letters) how to going back to image.